# Is it a problem that I didn't report back in person to the Italian embassy upon my return to India?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, sweden, schengen-visas

I visited Europe in 2015 with a Schengen visa issued by Italy. It required that, on my return, I report back to the Italian embassy in Delhi. The day I planned my visit was a Friday and I was not aware that the embassy was closed. I was not able to visit the embassy in Delhi after that.

However, I did report back to the Italian consulate in Mumbai, where they acknowledged my visa and asked me to get it approved at the Italian embassy in Delhi. I forwarded the stamped visa (3 months after returning) to the embassy in Delhi, but never received an acknowledgment.

Fast forward to 2018 and I am applying for a visa, this time through Sweden. Would I face any problems in getting the visa?

Comment: Nobody can tell you yes or no. You will find out when your reapply.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately we cannot predict the future. The only way to answer your question is to reapply for a Schengen visa, attaching a letter which explains your circumstances.